# Result NuSoap to String PHP

Tags: php, nusoap

I'm php beginner and start to learning nusoap. 
Here is my code:

```
<?php
include_once('nusoap/nusoap.php');
include_once('nusoap/class.wsdlcache.php');


$url = 'http://localhost:8082/ws/server.php?wsdl';

$client = new nusoap_client($url, true);

$proxy = $client->getProxy();

$username = 'admin';
$password = 'admin123';

$token = $proxy->GetToken($username, $password);

//this code to display ListTable

$table = $proxy->ListTable($token);
?>
```

How to display the list of table? If I try to use this code: **print_r($table)** , I got this result:

```
    Array
(
    [error_code] => 0
    [error_desc] => 
    [result] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [table] => student
                    [category] => Ref
                    [information] => student information
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [table] => id_number
                    [category] => Ref
                    [information] => Student ID Number
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [table] => Address
                    [category] => Ref
                    [information] => Student Address
                )
    )
)
```

if I use this code to print the value: **print_r($table, TRUE)** but the result is blank white page.

I would like the output like this:

```html
<table border='1'>
  <tr>
    <td>Table</td>
    <td>Category</td>
    <td>Information</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>student</td>
    <td>Ref</td>
    <td>student information</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>id_number</td>
    <td>Ref</td>
    <td>student id number</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>information</td>
    <td>Ref</td>
    <td>student address</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<?php

echo "<table><tr>";

foreach($table['result'] as $r){
echo "<td>".$r['table']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$r['category']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$r['information']."</td>";
}

echo "</tr></table>";

?>
```